# Upload files through submit button of html instead of upload button of flash

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I have atleast 50 fields in my html form and I have integrated flash file uploader for multiple file uploading.

Another reason of used for flash file uploader is we can't get filesize before uploading file in IE. for get the file size in IE i used flash.

EAflashuploader integration works successfully.

But my requirement is litle bit different.

In EAflashuploader there is upload button when you click on that all added file uploaded.
But I want to disable this upload button and upload file should be upload when i click on
Html submit button.

In short i want to upload files through submit button in html instead of upload button in flash.

when form submit i can get all the data in post method.

Project link : http://www.triggergmbh.com/EAFUpload/PHP/simpleupload.php

EAFlashUpload link : http://www.easyalgo.com/examples/eaflashupload/simpleupload.aspx

EAFlashUpload Doc link : http://www.easyalgo.com/support/docs/eaflashupload/

Javascript function

```
    function doSendForm() {  
        EAFlashUpload.uploadFiles();  
        document.forms["id_form"].submit();    
    }
```

HTML code

```
<div style="width:450px;height:350;background:#EFEFEF;">  
<form name="id_form" id="id_form" method="post" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">  
<div id="EAFlashUpload_holder"></div>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="EAFUpload/swfobject.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var params = {  
        BGcolor: "#ffffff",  
        wmode: "window"  
    };  

    var attributes = {  
        id: "EAFlashUpload",  
        name: "EAFlashUpload"                               
    };  

    var flashvars = new Object();   

    var uploadUrl = "simpleupload.php"; 
    if (!document.all) {  
        uploadUrl = "../" + uploadUrl;  
    }  
    flashvars["uploader.uploadUrl"] = uploadUrl;  
    flashvars["viewFile"] = "EAFUpload/TableView.swf";  
    flashvars["view.uploadButton.visible"] = "false";  

    swfobject.embedSWF("EAFUpload/EAFUpload.swf", "EAFlashUpload_holder", "450", "350", "10.0.0", "EAFUpload/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);  

    function EAFlashUpload_onMovieLoad(errors)  
    {  
        if(errors != "")  
            alert(errors);   
    }  
</script>
    <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></p>  
    <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></p>  
    <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="doSendForm();" style="padding:10px;font-size:20px;">&nbsp;  
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EAFlashbutton seems to have flexible configuration options and a Javascript API.

You should be able to 1) hide the Flash upload button and 2) trigger the upload externally via Javascript.

#### 1) hiding the button

Buttons have a [`visible` property](http://www.easyalgo.com/support/docs/eaflashupload/EAFlashUpload/tableview.buttons.html#uploadButton), so you should be able to hide them with something like this:

```
flashvars["view.uploadButton.visible"] = "false";
```

#### 2) Triggering the upload

Use the [`uploadFiles()` method](http://www.easyalgo.com/support/docs/eaflashupload/EAFlashUpload/javascript.api.html#uploadFiles) of the Javascript API.

Comment: with help of flashvars["view.uploadButton.visible"] = "false"; I have disable the Upload button.

I have called doSendForm(); function on onclick event of submit button. and i used document.forms["id_form"].submit(); for submit the form. after form submit files data are not posted to submited form.

let me know where i have to put uploadFiles() method.

Comment: I think on flash upload button ajax request should be called.

Comment: I would guess you need to wait until the Flash uploader has finished before you submit the outer HTML form. There are probably events for that in the Javascript API.

Comment: Actually, the creators of the Flash uploader had your use case in mind. It can be integrated into a HTML `<form>` and it will send the form inputs together with the files. Look at this example: http://www.easyalgo.com/quickstart/util/srcview.aspx?path=/Examples/EAFlashUpload/UploadDescription.src